# iPhone browser does not load text just images

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I have an iPhone 6s with iOS 9. For some reason it takes forever to load text on a Web page while all images are shown in a very short time when navigating to a new page. I tried CNN.com and other news sites as well. They all seem to behave the same while... Any ideas what can be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have any content blockers? Does it happen on both WiFi and 3G/LTE?

Comment: No content blockers and it seems to be happening on mobile net only

Comment: Have you swiped all apps closed, then forced a shutdown (hold down power & home button.)

Comment: Wifi or cellular?  Our work wifi dns blocks a lot of content from websites and I see similar things.

Comment: Cellular connection. Does not happen on WiFi

Comment: Restart did not helped either

Comment: Have you tried holding down the 'reload page' icon in the address bar and selecting 'load without content blocking' to bypass the built-in content blocking?

Comment: Are you on a fast internet connection? It sounds like a CSS web font problem. On webkit-based browsers, like Safari or Chrome, the text is invisible until the web font is loaded, and that sometimes happens after everything else is loaded. Lots of news sites use web fonts.

Comment: @fbara if I hold down the reload button in mobile Safar the only option I get is "Request Desktop Site"

Comment: @Samuel I think you are on to something. It seems like the browser downloading something in the background while everything but the text is shown. This happens only on 3G/LTE. On wifi, the page is loaded instantly... Is there a way to fix/work around this issue somehow?

Comment: There are some things that web developers can do to minimize the problem, but I don't know of anything the person viewing the site can do on their end. Web fonts are fonts hosted on a server somewhere, as opposed to standard/common fonts like Helvetica or Times New Roman that load quickly because they're built into your phone or computer. Safari and Chrome display invisible text until the web font is loaded, while Firefox and Opera display unstyled text (i.e. with a substitute font). You can see some screenshot comparisons here: https://remysharp.com/2009/06/23/safaris-problem-with-font-face